# Jmeter: BeanshellAssertion Error: Method Not Found In Class

Tags: class, jdbc, jmeter, beanshell

I simply want to read response from jdbc sampler and use it in an http request.

I created a BeanShellAssertion Script under a jdbc request and wrote just the below code, nothing else.

```
if(vars.getObjects("jdbcresult1").size!=0)
{
   String jdbcresult1=vars.getObjects("jdbcresult1").get(0).get("jdbctrackingnumber1")+"";
   vars.put("trackingnumber1",jdbcresult1);
   log.info("TrackingNumber1 is: "+trackingnumber1);
}
```

Error:

> 2020-08-13 23:32:47,030 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error
> invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import
> java.lang.Object; if(vars.getObjects("jdbcresult1").size!=0) {
> String  . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method getObjects(
> java.lang.String ) not found in
> class'org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables'
>
> 2020-08-13 23:32:47,030 WARN o.a.j.a.BeanShellAssertion: Error in
> BeanShellAssertion

**Question1:** How do you decide what should you use to write a code to read jdbcresponse value:
a. beanshellassertion
b. beanshellpostprocessor
c. beanshelllistener

**Question2:** Solution to the original problem, to resolve the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
 vars.getObjects(...)
```

does not exist.

It should be :

```
 vars.getObject(...)
```

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html

Also it’s better to use JSR223 Assertion:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion

Comment: Thanks UBIK, JSR223 assertion has worked for me :-) I just wrote log.info("Hello All: "+vars.get("jdbctrackingnumber1_" + 1));